# How to parse JSON object to CSV file using json2csv nodejs module

Tags: json, node.js, csv

I'm currently learning how to parse a JSON object to a CSV file using the [json2csv](https://npmjs.org/package/json2csv) node module. Have never worked with JSON before, so this is all new to me.

My JSON object is formatted like this:

```
{
 "car":
      {
          "name":["Audi"],
          "price":["40000"],
          "color":["blue"]
      }
}
```

And the output CSV file is formatted like this:

```
"car","name","price","color"
{"name":["Audi"],"price":["40000"],"color":["blue"]},,,
```

How would I be able to get the CSV output to look like this instead?

```
name, price, color
"Audi",40000,"blue"
```

I understand I can call fields directly for just regular JSON data, but I don't understand how it would work under a JSON object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

json2csv only support a flat structure where fields are direct children of the json root.

if you wish to change it, consider cloning the code and do something like the following:

```
// createColumnContent function changed from original code
var createColumnContent = function(params, str, callback) {
  params.data.forEach(function(data_element) {
    //if null or empty object do nothing
    if (data_element && Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data_element).length > 0) {
      var line = '';
      var eol = os.EOL || '\n';
      params.fields.forEach(function(field_element) {
        // here, instead of direct child, getByPath support multiple subnodes levels
        line += getByPath(data_element, field_element.split('.'), 0) + params.del;
      });
      //remove last delimeter
      line = line.substring(0, line.length - 1);
      line = line.replace(/\\"/g, '""');
      str += eol + line;
    }
  });
  callback(str);
};

var getByPath = function(data_element, path, position) {
  if (data_element.hasOwnProperty(path[position])) {
    if (position === path.length - 1) {
      return JSON.stringify(data_element[path[position]]);
    }
    else {
      return getByPath(data_element[path[position]], path, position + 1)
    }
  }
  else {
    return '';
  }
}
```

usage:

```
json2csv({data: json, fields: ['car.name.0', 'car.price.0', 'car.color.0']}, function(err, csv) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file saved');
  });
});
```

output file content:

```
"car.name.0","car.price.0","car.color.0"
"Audi","40000","blue"
```

as a side note, to clone and work with your own version:

```
git clone https://github.com/zeMirco/json2csv.git
```

add changes...

to use changed version:

```
npm install /local/path/to/repo
```

Answer (score 9):

```
const { Parser } = require('json2csv');

let myCars = {
    "car":
    {
        "name": ["Audi"],
        "price": ["40000"],
        "color": ["blue"]
    }
};

let fields = ["car.name", "car.price", "car.color"];

const parser = new Parser({
    fields,
    unwind: ["car.name", "car.price", "car.color"]
});

const csv = parser.parse(myCars);

console.log('output',csv);
```

will output to console

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can also direct json2csv to use a sub array within your JSON object by addressing it with `.<name>` after your JSON object in the data section of json2csv.

In your case, this might look something like:

```js
const json2csv = require('json2csv');
const fs = require('fs');

var json = {
 "car":[
  {
   "name":"Audi",
   "price":"40000",
   "color":"blue"
  }
 ]
};

json2csv({data: json.car, fields: ['name', 'price', 'color']}, function(err, csv) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  fs.writeFile('cars.csv', csv, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('cars file saved');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this using the parse method and formatting my json data as an array of objects.

```
const { parse, Parser } = require('json2csv');
const data = [
     {key: value, key2: value2 },
     {key: value3, key2: value4 }
     ];
const fields = ['key', 'key2'];
const csv = parse(data, { fields });
```

Then do what you need with the csv variable.

Answer (score 3):

The input is bad format, it should like [json2csv document](https://github.com/zeMirco/json2csv):

```
var json2csv = require('json2csv');

var json = [
  {
    "car": "Audi",
    "price": 40000,
    "color": "blue"
  }, {
    "car": "BMW",
    "price": 35000,
    "color": "black"
  }, {
    "car": "Porsche",
    "price": 60000,
    "color": "green"
  }
];

json2csv({data: json, fields: ['car', 'price', 'color']}, function(err, csv) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  fs.writeFile('file.csv', csv, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('file saved');
  });
});
```

The content of the "file.csv" should be

```
car,       price, color
"Audi",    40000, "blue"
"BMW",     35000, "black"
"Porsche", 60000, "green"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying! Could you let me know why the input is bad format? Ultimately, what I'm doing is converting from XML to JSON first, and then JSON to CSV. The XML to JSON input/output will be similar to how I have the original format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about you guys, but i like small packages that just work as expected without a lot of extra configuration, try using **jsonexport**, works really well with objects, arrays, .. and its fast!

Install

```
npm i --save jsonexport
```

Usage

```
const jsonexport = require('jsonexport');
const fs = require('fs');

jsonexport({
 "car":[
  {
   "name":"Audi",
   "price":"40000",
   "color":"blue"
  }
 ]
}, function(err, csv) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  fs.writeFile('cars.csv', csv, function(err) {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    console.log('cars.csv saved');
  });
});
```

https://github.com/kauegimenes/jsonexport

Answer (score -1):

Check out [Underscore.js pluck method](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) - if you pass `_.pluck(json, 'car')` to json2csv's `data` instead of the original `json`, you should get what you're looking for.