# JS: Converting json and allowing client to download as csv without saving to server

Tags: json, node.js, csv

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620771/how-to-parse-json-object-to-csv-file-using-json2csv-nodejs-module) several ways were proposed to parse a json array into csv.

However in the answers given, fs is used to write the csv too. I am wondering whether it is possible to just convert a csv and make it available for the client to download without having to write it somewhere in the server? After all, the json already exists and writing a csv seems like duplication.

In my case I have a server with a mongodb collection which I'd like to make available portions of to clients as a csv.

thank you for your help!

Comment: Sure there is, just output the csv in `res.send` with a Content-Disposition header set to  `"attachment;filename=myfilename.csv"`, and it downloads

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the JSON to csv with client side javascript like in the question you linked.
Then you can make the browser download that file as a csv as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18197341/2740933)

So like this:

```
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

var json = getYourJSONObject();
var csv = convertJSONToCsv(json);

var name = "filename";
download(name+".csv",csv);
```

Hope this help :)