# How to convert JSON response Of BigQuery to CSV using Node.js (f and v keys)?

Tags: json, node.js, csv, google-bigquery

I am getting following as a response from bigquery and i want to convert this whole data to CSV.

```
"rows": [
 {
  "f": [        
    {
      "v": "1"
    },
    {
      "v": "204"
    },
    {
      "v": "1464830471"
    },
    {
      "v": "4"
    },
    {
      "v": "5593693585347748"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "f": [        
    {
      "v": "1"
    },
    {
      "v": "205"
    },
    {
      "v": "1464865550"
    },
    {
      "v": "2"
    },
    {
      "v": "5593693585347748"
    }
  ]
}
```

]

Now i want this f and v to be converted like this.

**data.csv**

```
1,204,1464830471,4,5593693585347748
1,205,1464865550,2,5593693585347748.
```

Here Bigquery responses consist of f and v key.thats make confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this if `x` is your object:

```
var x = {"rows":[{"f":[{"v":"1"},{"v":"204"},{"v":"1464830471"},{"v":"4"},{"v":"5593693585347748"}]},{"f":[{"v":"1"},{"v":"205"},{"v":"1464865550"},{"v":"2"},{"v":"5593693585347748"}]}]};

var output = "";

x.rows.map(function(e){

    var values = [];
    e.f.map(function(o){
        values.push(o.v);
    }); 
     output += values.join(",") + "\n";
})

console.log(output);
```

Prints out this:

```
1,204,1464830471,4,5593693585347748
1,205,1464865550,2,5593693585347748
```

Comment: its working,but i am going to process 100GB of data is this method is feasible for processing the JSON.

Comment: Oh ok that is too big to load it to memory. You have to use streams to continuously read json objects. Wrap my code into this json stream based reader. https://www.npmjs.com/package/stream-json. The "endObject" event should help you.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

- Change the query to use `GROUP_CONCAT` (legacy SQL) or `STRING_AGG` (standard SQL) in order to generate a comma-separated string for each row.
- Don't modify the query, and use a utility such as json2csv to convert to CSV within your application. Possibly relevant question: [How to parse JSON object to CSV file using json2csv nodejs module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620771/how-to-parse-json-object-to-csv-file-using-json2csv-nodejs-module)

Comment: Yes, here is a link to the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#group_concat